# How to constrain generic function associated types

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, associated-types

I'm trying to take two protocols that both have the same associated type and return the same type, but not having luck.

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    associatedtype AssociatedType
}

func myFunc<T: MyProtocol, R: MyProtocol>(arg: T) -> R
    where T.AssociatedType == R.AssociatedType {
        return arg //Error-> Cannot convert return expression of type 'T' to return type 'R'
}
```

Is something like this possible in Swift?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? I appreciate that you tried to make a minimal viable example, but this example doesn't effectively communicate the intent for what problem you were trying to solve using this approach.

Comment: I’m trying to hide a bunch of functions by referring to an object as a protocol.

Comment: If the protocol needs to be generic, then you're best off by using a type eraser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two types (call them `T` and `R`) are not the necessarily the equivalent just because they conform to the same protocol and use the same associated type.

By that reasoning, `Array<Int>` is the same as `Set<Int>`, and should be freely interchangeable, because they both conform to `Collection` where the `Element` is `Int`.

Here's another counter example:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    associatedtype AssociatedType

    init()
}

protocol MySubProtocol1: MyProtocol where AssociatedType == Int {}
protocol MySubProtocol2: MyProtocol where AssociatedType == Int {}

struct S1: MySubProtocol1 {}
struct S2: MySubProtocol2 {}

func myFunc<T: MyProtocol, R: MyProtocol>(arg: T) -> R
    where T.AssociatedType == R.AssociatedType {
        return arg as! R // Let's see what would happen. Don't do this!
}

func produce<T: MySubProtocol1>(type: T.Type) -> T {
    return T()
}

func consume<T: MySubProtocol2>(arg: T, ofType: T.Type) {
    print(arg)
}

consume(arg: myFunc(arg: produce(type: S1.self)), ofType: S2.self)
```

> Terminated due to signal: `ABORT TRAP (6)`
>
> Could not cast value of type `'main.S1'` (`0x100e44210`) to `'main.S2'` (`0x100e44228`).